# how to remove # from url URL rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Our url has # in our program, how do we hide it from user

```
example: www.example.com/#/privacypolicy
```

need to change that to [www.example.com/privacypolicy](http://www.example.com/privacypolicy)

is where any way to achive this using webconfig

Answer (score 0):

URL won't send any part to server after #, that means server won't get part of privacypolicy,so use url.encode is a great way to make complete url send to server.
Hash Tags in the URL serve a special purpose to the client browser, not to the server.so Browser did not anything after the '#' character.

```
 <rule name="#" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.example.com/{UrlEncode:{C:1}}" />
```

This will make [www.example.com/#/privacypolicy](http://www.example.com/#/privacypolicy) become [www.example.com/%2F#/privacypolicy](http://www.example.com/%2F#/privacypolicy), so that server can get privacypolicy.